# It showing blank page instead of some display

Tags: php

I write this php code but I haven't find any mistake, If you can than please let me know !

**My php code:-**

Insert title here

```
<body>

<?php

echo displayForm();


function displayForm(){

        $r=' ';

        $r.='<form method="post" action="processOrderTicketes.php">';

    //table
    $r.='<table>';

    $r.=displayRow('First Name:', '<input type="text" name="firstName"/>');
    $r.=displayRow('Last Name:', '<input type="text" name="lastName"/>');
    $r.=displayRow('Number of Ticketes:', '<input type="text" name="numberofticketes"/>');

    $r.='</table>';

    $r.='</form>';

    return $r;
}





function displayRow($left,$right){

    $r=' ';

//build it
$r='<tr>';
$r='<td>'.$left.'</td>';
$r='<td>'.$right.'</td>';
$r='</tr>';

return $r;
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: What does the PHP error log say?

Comment: in your `displayRow` function your overwriting the contents of the `r` variable on each assignment

Comment: It showing no error and no result either !

Comment: Even after changing displayRow function, still nothing happen !

Comment: Missing the `<head> bit for a start. Peraps might be a good idea to view the page source

Comment: i tried the script myself. If you change it with the suggetion of J Young, it should work...

Comment: Also, it ia always good to use variables names that covers the content. I'll use in `displayForm`, the var $form i.s.o. $r. and in `displayRow`$row i.s.o. $r

Answer (score 4):

Instead of appending values in `displayRow`, you are constantly re-assigning a new value to `$r`.

To confirm, this is how your code should look:

```
        $r=' ';

        //build it
        $r.='<tr>';
        $r.='<td>'.$left.'</td>';
        $r.='<td>'.$right.'</td>';
        $r.='</tr>';

        return $r;
    }
?>
</body>
```

**Edit:**

This is working on my webspace.

```
<body>
    <?php   

        echo displayForm();

        function displayForm() {
            $r=' ';

            $r.='<form method="post" action="processOrderTicketes.php">';

            //table
            $r.='<table>';

            $r.=displayRow('First Name:', '<input type="text" name="firstName"/>');
            $r.=displayRow('Last Name:', '<input type="text" name="lastName"/>');
            $r.=displayRow('Number of Ticketes:', '<input type="text" name="numberofticketes"/>');

            $r.='</table>';

            $r.='</form>';

            return $r;
        }

        function displayRow($left, $right) {
            $r=' ';

            //build it
            $r.='<tr>';
            $r.='<td>'.$left.'</td>';
            $r.='<td>'.$right.'</td>';
            $r.='</tr>';

            return $r;
        }


    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Anyways why we put "." after $r ?

Comment: To append value in $r variable

Comment: The .= tells PHP to append the value (ie. $r = "foo"; $r .= "bar"; would return $r = "foobar", whereas $r = "foo"; $r = "bar"; would return $r = "bar" as you have re-assigned the value).

Comment: $r.=''; is equal to $r=$r.'';

Comment: Thank you so much J young and Deadlock and others who helped me !